# Html buttons moving theirselves when there are multiple text lines

Tags: html, css

I have this html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href="css/quiz.css">
        <title>DoffyQuiz</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="img/doffycorp.png">
        <script src="js/quiz.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <header>
        <img src="img/doffycorp.png" id="logo">
    </header>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="encadre">
                <div class="qdiv"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
                <div class="afdiv">
                    <button class="fbut">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed in lectus vitae nisl dictum elementum. Fusce sodales mi nisl, eget.</button>
                    <button class="fbut">Button 2</button>
                    <button class="fbut">Button 3</button>
                    <button class="fbut">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris scelerisque mattis pellentesque. Ut erat ligula, consequat ut arcu vel, malesuada vulputate urna. Integer vitae libero massa. Ut risus purus, dapibus ac dui vitae, feugiat ornare lorem. Phasellus ultricies lacus sit.</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and this CSS code

```
@font-face { /* font face (toute la page, Questrial)*/
    font-family: 'Questrial';
    src: url('../fonts/Questrial-Regular.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/Questrial-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../fonts/Questrial-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('../fonts/Questrial-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../fonts/Questrial-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('../fonts/Questrial-Regular.svg#Questrial-Regular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: swap;
}

body {
    background-color: #51fdb4;
    font-family: 'Questrial';
}

#encadre {
    background-color: #eee;
    width: 950px;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding:30px;
}

#logo {
    width:253px;
    height:253px;
    margin:auto;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

span {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #EF767A;
}

.fbut {
    outline: none;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    border-radius: 8px;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin: 10px;
    font-family: 'Questrial';
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 1px;
    text-align: center;
}

.fbut:hover {
    transition: background-color .2s ease-in;
    background-color:#ddd;
}

.fbut:not(:hover) {
    transition: background-color .2s ease-in;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.afdiv {
    margin: auto;
    width:845px;
}

.qdiv {
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

And I tried many things, but when the button's text contain more than 1 line of text, the button moves itself to the bottom (see the img). How can i make them be centered, as on the second image (which has 1 line per button) ?
[image: Image with misplaced buttons]
[image: Image with well placed buttons]

I think it deals with CSS but I tried a lot of thigs, but didn't find out.

Thanks for any answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve this result using `grid` layout

```
div.afdiv {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
```

```css
@font-face {
  /* font face (toute la page, Questrial)*/
  font-family: 'Questrial';
  src: url('../fonts/Questrial-Regular.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/Questrial-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/Questrial-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/Questrial-Regular.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/Questrial-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/Questrial-Regular.svg#Questrial-Regular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: swap;
}

body {
  background-color: #51fdb4;
  font-family: 'Questrial';
}

#encadre {
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 950px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 30px;
}

#logo {
  width: 253px;
  height: 253px;
  margin: auto;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

span {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #EF767A;
}

.fbut {
  outline: none;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  border-radius: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 10px;
  font-family: 'Questrial';
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 1px;
  text-align: center;
}

.fbut:hover {
  transition: background-color .2s ease-in;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.fbut:not(:hover) {
  transition: background-color .2s ease-in;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.afdiv {
  margin: auto;
  width: 845px;
}

.qdiv {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}


/* CHANGES */

div.afdiv {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="img/doffycorp.png" id="logo">
</header>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="encadre">
    <div class="qdiv">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    </div>
    <div class="afdiv">
      <button class="fbut">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed in lectus vitae nisl dictum elementum. Fusce sodales mi nisl, eget.</button>
      <button class="fbut">Button 2</button>
      <button class="fbut">Button 3</button>
      <button class="fbut">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris scelerisque mattis pellentesque. Ut erat ligula, consequat ut arcu vel, malesuada vulputate urna. Integer vitae libero massa. Ut risus purus, dapibus ac dui vitae, feugiat ornare lorem. Phasellus ultricies lacus sit.</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Buttons are inline elements. To render them side-by-side, the browser engine tries to match their baselines, which in you case is the last line of text in each button.

You can get rid of this problem by declaring a `flex` layout for their parent.

Just add to your CSS:

```
.afdiv {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Runnable result based on your code:

```css
@font-face { /* font face (toute la page, Questrial)*/
    font-family: 'Questrial';
    src: url('../fonts/Questrial-Regular.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/Questrial-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../fonts/Questrial-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('../fonts/Questrial-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../fonts/Questrial-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('../fonts/Questrial-Regular.svg#Questrial-Regular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: swap;
}

body {
    background-color: #51fdb4;
    font-family: 'Questrial';
}

#encadre {
    background-color: #eee;
    width: 950px;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding:30px;
}

#logo {
    width:253px;
    height:253px;
    margin:auto;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

span {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #EF767A;
}

.afdiv {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.fbut {
    outline: none;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    border-radius: 8px;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin: 10px;
    font-family: 'Questrial';
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 1px;
    text-align: center;
}

.fbut:hover {
    transition: background-color .2s ease-in;
    background-color:#ddd;
}

.fbut:not(:hover) {
    transition: background-color .2s ease-in;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.afdiv {
    margin: auto;
    width:845px;
}

.qdiv {
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href="css/quiz.css">
        <title>DoffyQuiz</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="img/doffycorp.png">
        <script src="js/quiz.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <header>
        <img src="img/doffycorp.png" id="logo">
    </header>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="encadre">
                <div class="qdiv"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
                <div class="afdiv">
                    <button class="fbut">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed in lectus vitae nisl dictum elementum. Fusce sodales mi nisl, eget.</button>
                    <button class="fbut">Button 2</button>
                    <button class="fbut">Button 3</button>
                    <button class="fbut">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris scelerisque mattis pellentesque. Ut erat ligula, consequat ut arcu vel, malesuada vulputate urna. Integer vitae libero massa. Ut risus purus, dapibus ac dui vitae, feugiat ornare lorem. Phasellus ultricies lacus sit.</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```